# Canvas-lms: SMTP From address may not be blank: nil

Tags: ruby, email, smtp

Instalé Canvas-Lms sin embargo, no he podido enviar correos desde el aplicativo, siempre me indica el error SMTP **From address may not be blank: nil**

Tengo configurado el outgoin_mail.yml de manera correcta sin embargo muestra el mismo error.

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir tu código para poderte ayudar de mejor manera?

Answer (score 0):

El error por lo que veo trata de que estas mandando vacío o nil el correo, no tanto de tu configuración.
Asegurate que el parámetro donde esta el correo no este vacio.